# Is there a link between FFI and timing?

Tags: haskell, ghc

**tl;dr**: I have an error in my test-suite that stops being an error when interpreted or slowed down.

So I have a bunch of functions that rely on `Numeric.GSL.Fitting` to do the heavy lifting and a *test-suite* exercising those functions.

I barely managed to stay sane when I tried to fix a failing test-case that failed but I couldn't find a fault in my code.

Taking the failing cases from `QuickCheck` and inspecting the results showed differences, but that is expected for noisy fitting.

At one point I just tried to run one test-case in *ghci* and found that, to my astonishment, all 100 iterations passed. Stumped, I did the same thing for other tests that failed and found that all of them passed fine when interpreted.

With that knowledge I removed anything I could think of that is different in the compiled code (ie `-O0`, removed `fast-math`) but to no avail.

The second thing I noticed is that the test actually passes when I `traceShowId` the result from the fitting in each iterations.

This all seems to hint at a problem that vanishes when it is running with a different timing (ghci being slower, tracing slowing it down). The FFI calls in `Numeric.GSL.Fitting` are `safe`, so that shouldn't be a problem.

Your guess is as good as mine ... but does anyone have an idea what could be the cause here?

Comment: You could dump the core after simplification in both the interpreted and compiled to check for differences there. That being said, without a [mcve], it's going to be hard to reproduce the behaviour and actually answer the question.